# Multiple shortcodes within a text

Tags: php, shortcode

I have the following text

> this is line one
>
> [gallery]
>
> this is line two
>
> [gallery]
>
> this is line three

I also have the following code in php

```
$text = 'this is line one [gallery] this is line two [gallery] this is line three';
$gallery = array('gallery name1', 'gallery name2');

foreach ($gallery as $key => $val) {
    $text = preg_replace('#\[gallery\]#si', $val, $text); 
}
```

I want to replace the first [gallery] with the first value of array $gallery and the second [gallery] with the second value of array $gallery.

How can i do this?

Comment: Please, take the [tour] and read the [ask] guide. SO is not a code writing service. We expect you to show us your currently written code (even if it is an attempt) and show some research effort.

Comment: Use preg_replace

Comment: i have already updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a limit so that only 1 entry gets changed:

```
$text = preg_replace('#\[gallery\]#si', $val, $text, 1); 
                                                     ^ add a limit
```

Now, on each iteration, 1 instance of `[gallery]` will get replaced.